# Having mainpage in HTML output only and not in LaTeX

Tags: doxygen

I've got a mainpage using a HTML table that I only want to be included in the HTML output of doxygen. It should *not* be included in the other outputs (currently only LaTeX).

Since that mainpage uses doxygen commands like \ref and \mainpage itself, the \htmlonly tag is unfortunately not an option.

Is there a way to limit a markup file to certain outputs only?

Comment: The only things I can quickly think of is to run twice and use an `\if` or `\cond` construct, another possibility might be to run once generating HTML and LaTeX and afterwards modify the refman.tex (by hand or a script) excluding the mainpage.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Out of the two I prefer the second option and will post my findings here. I presume that an essentially empty markup file (due to the \if condition not being met) is ignored by doxygen?

Comment: The essential empty file is not necessarily ignored by doxygen only the part inside the `\if` or `\cond` so some parts may stay lingering around.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I ended up running doxygen twice, once for HTML output and once for LaTeX output. This gives me the flexibility to change other settings for different outputs as well, which is also something I was looking at.

So the dox file for my mainpage now looks like

```
/**
\if MySpecialFlagForHTMLOnly
\mainpage notitle
...
\endif
**/
```

My default doxyfile has `GENERATE_HTML = YES` and `GENERATE_LATEX = NO`. It also defines `MySpecialFlagForHTMLOnly` in `ENABLED_SECTIONS`.

Now for a second automated run, I change both `GENERATE_HTML` and `GENERATE_LATEX` and clear `MySpecialFlagForHTMLOnly` from `ENABLED_SECTIONS`.

Comment: I don't know how you change the configuration variables but when you do this by hand or by means of a script it maybe worthwhile to look at the FAQ: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_cmdline

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that is indeed handy as well! I might take that approach for other projects.